# Adding security questions to my Django site

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to ask the user for **two** security questions and their corresponding answers. The security questions will be provided by me, so it will be some kind of `<select>`. I created a model to store the user profile named `UserProfile`. It looks like:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    phone1 = models.CharField(help_text='Primary phone number')
    phone2 = models.CharField(help_text='Secondary phone number', blank=True)
    ...
```

I could do something like:

```
SECURITY_QUESTIONS_CHOICES = (
    ('PN', 'What is your telephone number?'),
    ('BF', 'What is the full name of your best friend?'),
    ...
    )
```

and add the following two fields to my model:

```
question1 = models.CharField(choices=SECURITY_QUESTIONS_CHOICES)
question2 = models.CharField(choices=SECURITY_QUESTIONS_CHOICES)
```

but I want to be able to modify the list of security questions, so I want it to be a model too.

My question is:

**What is the best way of having two fields that point to the same model**?

- Having only one field (eg. `questions`) which is a ManyToMany relationship to `SecurityQuestion`, and restricting the number to **2** in the registration form?
- Having two fields (`question1` and `question2`) where each one is a `ForeignKey` to `SecurityQuestion`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer create a separate model for all security questions. It gives you flexibility.

```
class SecurityQuestions(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'security_questions'
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ----
    ----
    user_questions = models.ManyToManyField(SecurityQuestions, through='SecurityQuestionsInter')


class SecurityQuestionsInter(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'security_questions_inter'

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    security_questions = models.ForeignKey(SecurityQuestions)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=False)
```

Comment: Good idea. I only have to make sure (through the forms) that the user will always have exactly 2 questions.

Comment: Keep in mind, these answers must be stored in a secure hash, just like a password, because they give you the same access to someone's account if the database is compromised.