# Django all-auth custom login form security?

Tags: django, security, django-allauth

I am planning to use Django all_auth custom login/register for the authentication. I am able to customize the form successfully. 
I am referring to this answer on stackoverflow: [Adding security questions to my Django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763099/adding-security-questions-to-my-django-site)

However, i cannot find a doc or information to add a security question and answer where i can hash the security answer?